# DNS solution for Dante SOCKS proxy

Tags: proxy, dns, socks, dante

I am trying to build a SOCKS solution for forward proxy. I am using dante SOCKS proxy as I have heard that big companies like google uses it as forward proxy solution.

on the SOCKS server, I am allowing based on FQDN's like google.com:443

Now the problem is, when the client constructs the packet, it tries to resolve google.com and gets X.X.X.X and sends connect request to SOCKS server. Now when the server receives the packets, it tries to reconstruct the packet to send out to internet, the server again does DNS resolution and if the server gets response as Y.Y.Y.Y, then it doesn't allow client's request as the destination IP in the client's request is different then the server's resolved IP address.

There was a solution in dante client which tells client to put a dummy destination address 0.0.0.1 and sends request to server and server processes it properly then. However that is creating a problem with internal domains as after using that dns resolution method, every requests goes through dante server :(

Please let me know

1. If there is any solution through which would help me in maintaining a DNS record expiry DC wide for e.g. google.com resolves to X.X.X.X and I should be able to resolve to this same IP address on 100's of DNS client and in case if the record changes, then it should immediately change/expire on client.
2. Any other proxy/socks solution which should be transparent to applications for forward proxy

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead with this solution in case anyone is curious to see the solution.

I used PowerDNS Auth Server with Pipe backend. The requests would land to PowerDNS server for resolution, it will pass on all the data to Pipe backend script with ABI, the script analysis the requests, sees if it is present under cached variable/memory map, if it is cache hit, it will respond using cached DNS records else it will use a DNS resolver to resolve that query like a resolver resolves normally.

PowerDNS version lower than 4.1 supports Pipe backend + resolver. This way, the request would first land to pipe backend script, if the script doesn't have any entries cached, it will not respond or will respond blank and then PowerDNS would resolve it with the mentioned resolver server in the configuration. However with version 4.1 and above, the resolver part is removed from PowerDNS Auth server hence you need to handle that behaviour via Pipe backend script.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your client. Firefox, for example, sends hostname to SOCKS proxy without resolving it. You can confirm that by Wireshark.

PS. assume you are using a SOCKS5/4a proxy. SOCKS4 does not support hostname. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS4a